# pipe not functioning

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

For some unfathomable reason, the pipe command breaks (and in a weird way too) when I use it in Terminal. Simply put, any command placed after the `|` will result in
 `zsh: command not found:  grep`
(`grep` being an example, but afaik any command will yield the same result).
I checked the path and the necessary directories are in there. As a matter of fact, `which grep` yields the expected `/usr/bin/grep`, so zsh *knows* where to look. I tried bash as well but the answer stays the same.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message you included in your question, there seem to be two spaces between `:` and `grep`. This indicates that you still have the special key pressed you needed to get `|` when you press <kbd>Space</kbd>. Try to make sure that you release the key before pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> (or omit space altogether, it's syntactically not required).

Comment: Wow. You do have a keen eye. Indeed that was it (and I feel so stupid). My finger must have stayed on the `alt` key a tad too long (or I'm typing too fast), repeatedly. Thanks a lot.